# SequelizeDatabaseError UPDATE using PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, orm, sequelize.js

I have 5 endpoint with 4 methods implemented. For GET, POST, DELETE all of them goes well. I don't understand why PUT method doesn't work. In my case, I need to update column first_name and last_name but it send me error like this:

```
{
    "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
    "parent": {
        "length": 221,
        "name": "error",
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "42703",
        "where": "PL/pgSQL function last_updated() line 3 at assignment",
        "file": "d:\\pginstaller_13.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\pl\\plpgsql\\src\\pl_exec.c",
        "line": "5170",
        "routine": "exec_assign_value",
        "sql": "UPDATE \"actors\" SET \"first_name\"=$1,\"last_name\"=$2,\"updatedAt\"=$3 WHERE \"actor_id\" = $4",
        "parameters": [
            "Anne ",
            "Anne",
            "2020-10-29 02:54:11.642 +00:00",
            "200"
        ]
    },
    "original": {
        "length": 221,
        "name": "error",
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "42703",
        "where": "PL/pgSQL function last_updated() line 3 at assignment",
        "file": "d:\\pginstaller_13.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\pl\\plpgsql\\src\\pl_exec.c",
        "line": "5170",
        "routine": "exec_assign_value",
        "sql": "UPDATE \"actors\" SET \"first_name\"=$1,\"last_name\"=$2,\"updatedAt\"=$3 WHERE \"actor_id\" = $4",
        "parameters": [
            "Anne ",
            "Anne",
            "2020-10-29 02:54:11.642 +00:00",
            "200"
        ]
    },
    "sql": "UPDATE \"actors\" SET \"first_name\"=$1,\"last_name\"=$2,\"updatedAt\"=$3 WHERE \"actor_id\" = $4",
    "parameters": [
        "Anne ",
        "Anne",
        "2020-10-29 02:54:11.642 +00:00",
        "200"
    ]
}
```

[This is how i tested in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w6Rf.png)

And this is my models:

```
const actor = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Actor = sequelize.define('actor', {
    actor_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    first_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    last_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
  });
  return Actor;
};

export default actor;
```

Help me, please. I have searched all around for the answer but still stuck.

UPDATE:
Here is my code when instantiate Sequelize:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DATABASE,
  process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  {
    dialect: 'postgres',
  },
);

const models = {
  Actor: sequelize.import('./actor'),
};

export { sequelize };

export default models;
```

And this is my app.js:

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

import models, { sequelize } from './models';
import routes from './routes';

const app = express();

// Application-Level Middleware
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  req.context = {
    models,
    me: await models.Actor,
  };
  next();
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Routes

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.render('index');
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
});
app.use('/actor', routes.actor);

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

// Start

sequelize.sync().then(async () => {
  app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
    console.log(`App listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`),
  );
});

module.exports = app;
```

[Also, this is my actual table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDxad.png)

Comment: Please attach 2 items: 1. Your code that calls the Sequelize 2. Your actual DB table structure

Comment: Hi, @aminits ! I have updated my questions. There are my code that calls Sequelize and picture that shows my table structure

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

This happen because I have deleted one column named "last_updated" that used as trigger when UPDATE, [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDIpm.png) . Now I disable that trigger and can successfully update.
My mistake, this DB I import from [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/) and didn't give attention to it